# Removing prefix from a string using a list of prefixes

Tags: swift, string

I was wondering how I could remove any prefix included in a list of prefixes (e.g: ["the", "a", "an"] from a given string (e.g: "A big red planet" -> "big red planet").

I have tried with this idea, but I do not know if it is the correct or the most efficient one.

```
extension String {
  func removing(prefixes: [String]) -> String {
    var resultString = self
    prefixes.map {
      if resultString.hasPrefix($0) {
        resultString = resultString.dropFirst($0.count).description
      }
    }
    return resultString
  }
}
```

Idea comes from this answer: [How to create a dictionary by first letter of title but ignore articles like "the" or "a/an" etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47455364/how-to-create-a-dictionary-by-first-letter-of-title-but-ignore-articles-like-th)

Comment: Just change the way you convert Substring to String. Instead of using description property you should use your Substring to initialise a new String. `String(resultString.dropFirst($0.count))`

Comment: I would also change the declaration to `removing(prefixes: [String])`

Comment: How would you treat a hypothetical case where one prefix follows another? For example "the a red planet". Would you strip both or only the first?

Comment: What is the difference between getting the description of a substring and a string construction from that substring?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist then it wouldn't be a prefix

Comment: @LeoDabus yes, editing it now, much cleaner and swift-like

Comment: `map` -> `forEach`. – And what about the whitespace after the removed prefix? (Currently that has the effect that only one prefix is removed.)

Comment: @MartinR what I was doing is sending the array of prefixes as follows: ["the ", "a ", "an "], that way the white space is also removed.

Comment: That's not what is in your code :) And then @DavidRönnqvist's remarks apply, and the result is dependent on the order of prefixes. – Try `"The a b c".removingPrefixes(["The ", "a "])` vs `"The a b c".removingPrefixes(["a ", "The "])`

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist the idea comes from a movie table view, so that by removing the articles, I get the main first letter of the movie (ej: "The big red planet" -> letter b). That way, I can sort the movies by its main first letter, ignoring the prefixes.

Comment: @Oxthor: Actually it comes from this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47455364/how-to-create-a-dictionary-by-first-letter-of-title-but-ignore-articles-like-th and your answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47459492 :)

Comment: @MartinR true, been wondering how to code this the best way

Comment: @MartinR just added the ref to that article in the post, sorry for that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an alternative using regular expression

The benefits:

- Case (in)sensitivity can be handled easily.
- An optional whitespace character following the prefix can be omitted, too.

The regex pattern is `^(prefix1|prefix2|prefix3)\\s?`. It matches beginning of the string (`^`) followed by one of the (quoted) prefixes (as `or` expression with the `|` operator) followed by an optional whitespace character (`\\s?`).

```
extension String {
    func removingPrefixes(_ prefixes: [String]) -> String {
        let pattern = "^(\(prefixes.map{"\\Q"+$0+"\\E"}.joined(separator: "|")))\\s?"
        guard let range = self.range(of: pattern, options: [.regularExpression, .caseInsensitive]) else { return self }
        return String(self[range.upperBound...])
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to take care if a prefix contains a regex special character, e.g. with `NSRegularExpression.escapedPattern(for:)`

Comment: Why don't you just return a Substring? And instead of returning self just `return self[...]` (this trick I learned from Hamish).

Comment: What is `\\Q` and `\\E` in pattern? (seems you described `\\s?` only)

Comment: @Top-Master Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30776860/regular-expression-q-e

Answer (score 0):

Change the comparison target to uppercase or lowercase to compare.

I do not know if this is the answer you want, but I hope it helps.

```
 prefixes.map {
        if resultString.hasPrefix($0.uppercased()) || resultString.hasPrefix($0.lowercased()) {
            resultString = resultString.dropFirst($0.count).description
        }
  }
```

**Full Source**

```
extension String {
   func removingPrefixes(_ prefixes: [String]) -> String {
       var resultString = self

       prefixes.map {
           if resultString.hasPrefix($0.uppercased()) || resultString.hasPrefix($0.lowercased()) {
              resultString = resultString.dropFirst($0.count).description
              print("\(resultString)")
          }
      }
      return resultString
   }
}

/**  print("A big red the planet".removingPrefixes(["the", "a", "an"]))
  *  result -> "big red the planet" */
```