# Python3 f-strings: how to avoid having to escape literal curly brackets?

Tags: python-3.x, escaping, f-string

Is there a way to avoid having to escape literal curly brackets characters in a python3 `f-string`?

For example if you want to output a json string or a chunk of CSS rules it's really inconvenient to have to convert all the `{` and `}` characters to `{{` and `}}` in case you want to use the f-string syntax.

I am aware that one can use the older syntax of e.g. `div {color: %s} % color`, `'text {}'.format(abc)` or [string templates](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#template-strings) but I wonder if there is a way to use the f-strings on raw text, preferably by having a way to mark the beginning and end of the 'raw' blocks with some kind of delimiter, for example similar to how you can use `\Q` and `\E` [in a java regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30776921/191246) in order to include unescaped raw characters in the regex.

As an alternative, is there something in the standard library that allows taking a chunk of raw text and converting it to an *f-string-safe* format? (again, similar to how you can use [Pattern.quote](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote-java.lang.String-) for java regexes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One can use [implicit string concatenation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation) to apply f-string formatting to only parts of a string.

> [...] Also note that literal concatenation can use different quoting styles for each component (even mixing raw strings and triple quoted strings), and **formatted string literals may be concatenated with plain string literals**.

```py
>>> hello = "world"
>>> "{hello}" f"{hello}" "!"
'{hello}world!'
```

This uses the exact same bytecode as the respective f-string with escapes.
Note that the whitespace is optional, but helpful for readability.

Comment: accepting as a functional workaround; really neat! thanks!

Comment: the output should in fact be `'{hello}world!'`, isn't it?

Comment: @ccpizza Oops, thanks for pointing that out. Yes, the output is ``'{hello}world!'``.

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways in python in which you can manupulate a string.

1. using f string
2. using str.format expressions
3. %-formatting expression

please refer to [this link](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#concatenating-strings)

Incase if you want, you can make your own custom function and call it.

```
def format_string(data,template):
    for key, value in data.items():
    return template.replace("#%s#" % key, str(value))
    
    
template ="<html><body>name is :#name# , profession is :#profession#<body></html>"
data ={"name":"Jack","profession":"student"}    
format_string(data,template)
```

Comment: I'm familiar with the existing formatting approaches. The question is specifically about ways to enable/disable f-string magic for specific blocks _or_ ootb ways to make any text 'f-string'-safe.