# Nest f-strings deeply in r-strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to pass the value `"How are you?"` of `question` to `body` so `body` has the value as shown below.

```py
question = "How are you?"
body = r’{
    "uid": "xxxx’,
    "msg": {
        "msgType": "text",
        "msgBody": {
            "content": "How are you"
        }
    }
}
```

I tried replacing `r` with `fr` and placing the curly braces deep inside but did not seem to work. The purpose I am doing this because I need to hash the string so I can include the hashed string in a URL.

Comment: Are you trying to build a JSON string? In that case, using the `json` module from the standard library might save you some headaches.

Comment: These `’“”’` are not valid quote characters. That's the most obvious reason your code would not work.

Comment: @khelwood The body variable can be printed in Python as expected.

Comment: @JamesChang Not from the code you have posted, it can't.

Comment: @khelwood Sorry, I guess it’s probably I am typing the question on my iPad. I am running the code on a laptop which is denied access to Stackoverflow.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python3 f-strings: how to avoid having to escape literal curly brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63315003/python3-f-strings-how-to-avoid-having-to-escape-literal-curly-brackets)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Unfortunately no. I’ve read this post. Mine is actually different because there is r-string involved.

Comment: `body = rf'{{"uid": "xxxx", "msg": {{"msgType": "text", "msgBody": {{"content": "{question}"}}}}}}'`?

Comment: @L3viathan It worked!  If you don’t mind, you can write down your answer with a little bit of explanation so more people would benefit. Thank you!

Comment: Okay, but that example is simply doing the escaping of literal curly brackets... that OP described... in the question that you said you read and didn't find helpful.

Comment: "Mine is actually different because there is r-string involved." How does this make a difference? You can combine *any* string literal with an f-string literal, including r-string literals. (FWIW, your example doesn't actually need to be an r-string.)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I see your point. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a more Pythonic way to achieve what you want by using the `json` module and a dictionary. Something like this:

```py
>>> import json
>>> question = 'How are you'
>>> body = {'uid': 'xxx', 'msg': {'msgType': 'text', 'msgbody': {'content': question}}}
>>> json.dumps(body)
'{"uid": "xxx", "msg": {"msgType": "text", "msgbody": {"content": "How are you"}}}'
```

To remove all the spaces after the separators, just pass the `separators` argument to `json.dumps()` like this:

```py
>>> json.dumps(body, separators=(',', ':'))
'{"uid":"xxx","msg":{"msgType":"text","msgbody":{"content":"How are you"}}}'
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This method does not generate the same hashed string as the one proposed in the comment section.  The product of `json.dumps()` leaves several spaces. I tried removing the spaces where you initialized `body` but nothing changed.

Comment: Just pass `separators=(',', ':')` to `json.dumps()`.

Comment: I would add `ensure_ascii=False’ in `json.dumps()` to make it suit my purpose but thank you. This should really be the best solution!

Comment: My pleasure. I'm glad to help.